# How can I deactivate?

Tags: julia, package-managers

I `activate` some package so I can add dependencies:

```
(v1.0) pkg> activate Example
Activating environment at `~/Example/Project.toml`

(Example) pkg> add Unicode
 Resolving package versions...
  Updating `~/Example/Project.toml`
  [4ec0a83e] + Unicode 
  Updating `~/Example/Manifest.toml`
  [4ec0a83e] + Unicode
```

Now I want to go back to the default environment. I tried the following:

```
(v1.0) pkg> activate v1.0
Activating new environment at `~/v1.0/Project.toml`
```

But this does not seem correct because the environment is empty. How can I activate the default environment in Julia?

Answer (score 10):

To go back to the default environment, use `activate` with no arguments:

```
(Example) pkg> activate
Activating environment at `~/.julia/environments/v1.2/Project.toml`
```

`pkg> activate v1.0` is not correct because `v1.0` is interpreted as the name of a directory in the current working directory.

You can learn more about `activate` with the built in `help` command:

```
pkg> help activate
```